# Is there any options for more dense / compact layout

Tags: angular-material2, teradata-covalent

is there any suggestion for a more dense/compact visual layout in overall design? I know Material Design has some dense options for some elements, but it is not enough. CRM or ERP applications may have a huge number of input elements on one page. As Covalent claims to be a framework for business applications, I thought maybe it offers something for the particular problem.

I am developing with Covalent Teradata 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment here - not an answer to the question.

I don't know about Covalent specifically, but the concept of "a huge number of input elements on one page" is very much the opposite of Material Design philosophy. I know from experience that migrating non-material interfaces to material design often requires significant redesign and a wholly different approach to the UI/UX.

A lot of things on the screen at one time is the first thing that has to change IMO. Trying to push material design "style" onto those older kinds of interface approaches makes for bad results IMO. Don't use Material Design halfheartedly - the results will be worse than not using it at all. Either embrace Material Design or stay away from it.

It's extremely important to get material design philosophy embedded in the minds of the experience architects/interface designers so that requirements, wire-frames, comps, mock-ups etc. all follow material design principles. You can't take a design that is not very "material" and easily make it material by using material design style, components etc. Material Design is as much about the interface "design" as it is about component style.